# Find the number $k$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Find the number $k$ such that the function
$$f(x)=\sqrt{kx-9}$$

has domain $[1/2,\infty)$ and then find its inverse $f^{−1}$, and $f^{−1}(\sqrt2)$.

Tried to find the $k$ by setting $\displaystyle k=\frac{(y^2+9)}{x}$ (where $f(x)=y$) but cant get any further.

Comment: **Hint:** Given $k\in \Bbb R$, the largest domain of $f$ is $\{x\in \Bbb R\colon kx-9\ge 0\}$, (note that this is an interval in disguise). To find the inverse set $y=\sqrt {kx-9}$ and solve for $x$.

Answer (score 2):

The square root as a function from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is not defined for negative numbers, so for it to be defined over the domain $[\frac{1}{2},\infty)$ you have to look, when $kx-9<0$. In order to do that we search the first zero of the function $g(x):=kx-9$. Since the $g(x)$ is a linear function and $\frac{1}{2}$ needs to be the smallest number in the domain, you can conclude the minimum needs to be at that value. So now we have 
$$
g(\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2} k - 9 = 0\\\Rightarrow k=18
$$
Now let $y:=f(x)$
$$
y=\sqrt{18x-9}\\y^2=18x-9\\\Rightarrow f^{-1}(y)=\frac{y^2+9}{18}\\f^{-1}(\sqrt{2})=\frac{11}{18}
$$